# How to set v-for index start from certain number?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a `v-for` loop through all the objects and assign the index number as a button id, but since the `slice` function stopped it, the index will count from zero. When I change to next page, I need to retrieve the right object with the right index number. How can I access and set the index in `v-for` so that I can make it start with certain number I want?

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    objects: [],
    limit: 12,
    searchName: ""
  },
  computed: {
    computedObj() {
      var merchants = this.limit
        ? this.objects.slice(num, this.limit)
        : this.objects;
    },
    filteredObjects: function() {
      var self = this;
      var merchants = this.limit
        ? this.objects.slice(num, this.limit)
        : this.objects;
      if (this.searchName != "") {
        var merchants = this.objects;
      }
      return merchants.filter(function(merchant) {
        return (
          merchant.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchName.toLowerCase()) !==
          -1
        );
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("url")
      // retreives an object
      .then(response => (this.objects = response.data.data));
  }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<tr v-for = "(object, index) in filteredObjects":key="object">
  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{ object.id }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.address }}</td>
  <!--  <td>{{ object.device_id }}</td> -->
  <td>{{ object.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.reward_percentage }}%</td>
  <td><span class="text-muted" style="white-space:nowrap;"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Sep 22, 1997</span> </td>
  <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <div class="label label-table label-success">
      <a :id="index" style="color: white" onclick="getIDView(this.id)">
        <i class="ti ti-eye"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="label label-table label-info">
      <a :id="index" style="color: white" onclick="getIDUpdate(this.id)">
        <i class="ti ti-pencil"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="label label-table label-danger">
      <a :id="index" style="color: white" onclick="getID(this.id)">
        <i class="ti ti-close"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: add a property as "index" to every object initially. so, that you can use that property while assigning button id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to modify **v-for** or look further than an **offset** data property and a **computed** property.

My main point is: do not modify your template - modify the list/array that you are feeding into your template. **v-for** is kinda' good as it is :)

Have a look at this snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    merchants: [],
    offset: 0
  },
  computed: {
    offsetMerchants() {
      if (this.offset < 2) this.offset = 0
      if (this.offset > 8) this.offset = 8
      return this.merchants.slice(this.offset, this.offset + 2)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchMerchants() {
      return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          // console.log(json)
          return json
        })
    },
    prev() {
      this.offset -= 2
    },
    next() {
      this.offset += 2
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.merchants = await this.fetchMerchants()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  The app downloads 10 users from the mock JSON API, but only shows 2 at a time - like pagination.<br /><br />
  <button @click="prev()">PREVIOUS MERCHANTS</button>
  <button @click="next()">NEXT MERCHANTS</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="merchant in offsetMerchants">
      ID: {{merchant.id}}<br /> Name: {{merchant.name}}<br /> Email: <a :href="'mailto:'+merchant.email">{{merchant.email}}</a><br />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see there's no meddling with the **v-for** - the only additional steps are

1. Adding **offset** to data
2. Not listing the data attribute directly, but a **computed** property.

Please note though, that **a computed property should return a value** - so don't use it to mutate the data (use methods for that).

So, you can pass this offset value as a param to the next page, or save it to localStorage or cookie, and use it in your next view.

Comment: I fixed it ! Thank you for help me! :)

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :)